# Where and how should I level up to catch the Legendary Birds?

Tags: pokemon-tower-defense

I haven't yet beat the Elite Four and would like to catch the legendary birds to help out with that.  Where should I go to most efficiently level up Pokemon of the appropriate types?  I intend to use a small number of type-appropriate sweepers for whatever level is chosen coupled with the majority of the team being low-level pokemon to be levelled up (either 1-5 or 2-4 depending on need). Is this a reasonable approach?